# get all chat members id pyrogram

Tags: python, pyrogram

How can I get all members of chat ids? I tried app.get_chat_members, but i need only user id, and nothing else. Tried this:

```
    countingusers=app.get_chat_members(f"{link}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app.get_chat_members()` only returns 200 members at a time. If you want to iterate over all members, you can use `app.iter_chat_members()` instead. To get just the user_id's, you could use a list comprehension:

```py
counting_users = [x.user.id for x in app.iter_chat_members(chat_id)]
```

Then your `counting_users` variable is a list of user_id's.

Comment: Thank you! Any ideas why it can get for example 5139 users when in fact there are 6178?

Comment: Likely because the Server simply refuses to return any more. I'm not Telegram, so no idea what actually causes that.

Comment: counting_users = [x.user.id for x in bot.iter_chat_members(chati)]
TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable i am getting error